# Angular scope not updated after $scope.$on event after $broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

In my controller I set up a `scope` variable called `diffData` like so:

```
$scope.diffData = $scope.diffSync.data;
```

In my view, I  bind to `diffData`'s num property like so:

```
<div class="sync-data"> num = {{diffData.num ? diffData.num : 0}}<div>
```

When I get the `$broadcast` event `new synced data` I replace my old `diffData` with new data that has an updated num like so:

```
$scope.$on('new synced data', function(event, data) {
    console.log('new synced data event', data);
    $scope.diffData = data;
});
```

The problem is that the new `num` is not updated in the view. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm assuming the console.log outputs new data as intended, ie, the event works ok?

Comment: have you tried calling `$scope.$applyAsync()` after the var is changed?

Comment: I just tried, no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `$scope.$apply`. Use $scope.$apply to change the scope variable.

```
$scope.$on('new synced data', function(event, data) {
    console.log('new synced data event', data);
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.diffData = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: I receive `angular.js:13424 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

Comment: @DanielKobe, you got me :D

Answer (score 1):

Generally when changes are not applied in Angular, you can call

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    // change vars here
})
```

Though I prefer the shorter solution:

```
// change vars
$scope.foo = 'bar';
$scope.$applyAsync();
```

This lets Angular apply the changes when it can and it does not conflict with other calls to `$apply()`